# udf spark Scala return case class

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

case class oneClass(a : Int , b: String , c :string)

val doSomthing = udf ((t1 : Seq[String], str : String , values : t2 Seq[String])
    => {
    val pos = t1.indexOf(str)
    if (pos >= 0) oneClass(pos, str,t2(pos))
    //if no control of pos possible return -1 ===> indexoutofboundsexception
    //if control the udf return Any then when I use it ===> Exception
    }
)
```

How I can return case class only when pos >= 0 and all the time return case class ??

Answer (score 1):

Either throw an exception if this should not happen (spark job will fail):

```
val doSomthing = udf ((t1 : Seq[String], str : String , t2 :Seq[String])=> {
  val pos = t1.indexOf(str)
  if (pos >= 0) oneClass(pos, str,t2(pos)) else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException
  }
})
```

otherwise use `Option`:

```
val doSomthing = udf ((t1 : Seq[String], str : String , t2 :Seq[String])=> {
  val pos = t1.indexOf(str)
  if (pos >= 0) Some(oneClass(pos, str,t2(pos))) else None
})
```

In the latter case, your result will be `null` in your DataFrame (`None` translates to `null`)

A pattern which can also be used it only to return a result if no exception is thrown :

```
val doSomthing = udf ((t1 : Seq[String], str : String , t2 :Seq[String])=> {
  scala.util.Try{
  val pos = t1.indexOf(str)
  oneClass(pos, str,t2(pos))
  }.toOption
})
```

This can be useful for testing, but I don't consider this good practice

Comment: thanks a lot , my need is when the pos is -1 then return nothing otherwise return oneClass(pos, str,t2(pos)

Comment: @K.T.A ?? Thats what I've written, `None` is sort of nothing..